# Highcharts - event after loading series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a few series in the chart. By clicking on some buttons, they are displayed. Series use "hide". Showing occurs only on clicks on the button.

```
{    
    id: "meq",
    name: "Margin/Equity",
    type: "candlestick",
    data: data.candle,
    color: "#ffa659",
    yAxis: 1,
    hide:true,
    visible:false
 }
```

But at the beginning of loading charts showing all the series and hiding late.
I want to put a picture until the complete download.
"Load" triggered before than I need. (All series are shown)

```
events: {
load: function() {
$(".loading-icon").addClass("hidden"); // class for image befor loading
}
}
```

And it does not help to put a picture in:

```
xAxis: {
events: {
afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
$(".loading-icon").addClass("hidden");
}
}
```

How do I hide the picture only after a full load series?

Comment: How about using chart.events.redraw? It is called each time series/point/axis is added or user zoom in the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to look into [addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29)

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-addseries/) from their documentation

So essentially, you're running

```
chart.addSeries({
    data: [1,3,45,6,3]
});
```